# "Not Pas Yisroel" certification Gardein, a frozen grocery item

Tags: hechsher-certification, pat-yisrael

Gardein is a brand of frozen food certified Kosher by [Kosher Check](https://koshercheck.org/kc-certified/companies/gardein).

Under their logo on the packaging for [Seven Grain Crispy Tenders](https://www.gardein.com/chickn-and-turky/classics/seven-grain-crispy-tenders) they've put the words "Not Pas Yisroel." The instructions also contain the remark "Food must be cooked thoroughly to 165 degrees Fahrenheit."

I don't understand that. I don't think I've ever seen another package that specifies that a food that still requires cooking is not Pas Yisroel. Why does this distinction arise?

Comment: Probably best to ask the kosher certification agency directly why they put that disclaimer (if they put that disclaimer)

Comment: To clarify- I believe the cook ti 165F requirement is because it is raw protein, even though it is not chicken. It is a food safety requirement.   Not related to Halacha (except general Halacha about not doing unsafe things, not eating discusting things, etc.)

Comment: I have absolutely no info or experience with this product, but it doesn't seem surprising to me that somethign could need cooking and not be pas yisroel. Consider a raw beef patty on a bun: it needs to be baked and the bun is not pas yisrael.

Comment: @Damila I'm not sure you followed my train of thought. A bag of flour is not certified with respect to Pas Yisroel. This issue of Pas Yisroel does not arise when buying a bag of flour because the food still requires cooking. I would think that the Gardein breading must still be undercooked, if the manufacturer instructs you to cook it before eating it. It makes no difference whether the maker is motivated by health or halacha or something else; his instruction is evidence that the grain is not yet completely cooked and is thus exempt from the Pas Yisroel requirement.

Comment: The bread crumbs don’t need to be baked, just the chicken. Reheating, doesn’t usually help to make it pas yisroel if it was fully baked  prior

Comment: Sefer Issur V’heter Ha’Aruch (43:11) writes that heating cold bread to make it fresh does not make the bread Pas Yisroel since there is no change in the degree of baking.